# Swift 3 how to present splitview controller modally?

Tags: swift3, uiviewcontroller, segue, xcode8, uisplitview

Hi I'm trying to present UiSplitViewController from UiViewController. I'm doing some search in UiViewController and based on result I display UiSplitViewController. How can I do it programatically? So far I tried 3 methods after googling

1.`self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SearchComplete", sender: self)`

2.`self.present(PrimarySplitViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)`

3.`let detailViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SplitView") as! UISplitViewController
            self.splitViewController?.viewControllers[1] = detailViewController`

None of the above methods have worked how can I solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

```
    let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SplitView") as! UISplitViewController

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
```

You have to set root view controller